# Detect if browser disables images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, modernizr

I need to detect if the browser disables images on the current page. Is this possible with JavaScript (jQuery/Modernizr)?

**Problem:** The project uses image sprites for icons and displays them like `<i class="icon-user"></i>`. The app is partially used by mobile users and some of them disable images if they're surfing with edge. As a result some buttons disappear.

The only thing I need is to display ***something*** (a gray square, circle…) if images are blocked. Via CSS class on the `<html>` element or so (`class="no-images"` e.g.). Writing alternative text between `<i>…</i>` is unhappily no option.

Thanks for your thoughts! I hope it exists a simple solution.

Comment: There is many workarounds already available online, what's wrong with google?

Comment: Maybe I used wrong keywords, sorry! I checked multiple combinations. The only results I got treated the `<noscript>` topic if js is disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following script:

```
function noimage()
{
    if ((document.getElementById('flag').offsetWidth==1 
         && document.getElementById('flag').readyState=='complete')
         ||(document.getElementById('flag').offsetWidth==1
         && document.getElementById('flag').readyState==undefined))
    {
         var objHead = document.getElementsByTagName('head');
         var objCSS = objHead[0].appendChild(document.createElement('link'));
         objCSS.rel = 'stylesheet';
         objCSS.href = 'alt.css';
         objCSS.type = 'text/css';
    }
}
```

And you need the following html markup:

```
<body onload="noimage();">
<img id="flag" src="clear.gif" alt="">
```

Just add it to the body. What this does is check the offsetWidth property to look for a 1x1 pixel image at the top of the browser. If it returns true it means that images are enabled.

If you need more info go [**here.**](http://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2011/10/detecting-if-images-are-disabled-in-browsers/)

Comment: Thank you! I've inverted the if conditions with !( … ) and added a CSS class to the `<html>` tag to handle the CSS.